# WEBScraping TypeError: sendmail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, smtplib

I have an error in my code. Is there an issue with connection to gmail? Or there is some other issue with my code?
Can you please show me how to fix this problem?

169.9
Garmin Forerunner 735XT GPS Multisport and Running Watch, Black/Grey                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\source\repos\RCS_WEB_SCRAPER\RCS_WEB_SCRAPER\RCS_WEB_SCRAPER.py", line 52, in               check_price()
File "C:\Users\User\source\repos\RCS_WEB_SCRAPER\RCS_WEB_SCRAPER\RCS_WEB_SCRAPER.py", line 29, in check_price           send_mail()
File "C:\Users\User\source\repos\RCS_WEB_SCRAPER\RCS_WEB_SCRAPER\RCS_WEB_SCRAPER.py", line 46, in send_mail             msg
TypeError: sendmail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'

MY CODE

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib
import time


URL = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Garmin-Forerunner-735XT-Multisport-Running-Black-Grey/dp/B01DWIY39A/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=garmin&qid=1582615813&sr=8-3'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'}


def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id ="productTitle").get_text()
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_dealprice").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price[1:6])

    if(converted_price < 160.00):
        send_mail()

    print(converted_price)
    print(title.strip())

    if(converted_price > 160.00):
        send_mail()

def send_mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()

    server.login('address', 'mAJnkzjfTqw8xJe')

    subject = 'Price decreased!'
    body = 'Now it is time to buy: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Garmin-Forerunner-735XT-Multisport-Running-Black-Grey/dp/B01DWIY39A/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=garmin&qid=1582615813&sr=8-3'

    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

    server.sendmail(
        'address@gmail.com',
        msg 
    )
    print('E-mail has been sent!')
    server.quit()

while(True):
    check_price()
    time.sleep(28800)
```

Comment: Show all your code, the code you have pasted has only 35 lines, yet your stack trace refers to lines 52 and 46. Running the code you pasted results in no errors

Comment: You do not show any code for the function  `check_price send_mail()` where the stack trace says the error originates from

Comment: @ChrisDoyle There is full code added already.

Comment: you are only pasing 2 args to server.sendmail the address and msg. But sendmail needs 3 args, from address, to address, message. So python is telling you you are not passing msg. because its taking the first 2 parameters you pass as from address and to address

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail see the documentation here. it states......`The required arguments are an RFC 822 from-address string, a list of RFC 822 to-address strings (a bare string will be treated as a list with 1 address), and a message string.`

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Then seems I'm missing 'from address' is that correct? I'm not sure what is the from address in this context, Amazon or Google?

Comment: The from address will be what ever address you want to present to the recipeint that the mail has come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sendmail requires 3 arguments to be passed to it. A from address, a list of to addresses, and a message thats to be sent.

from the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail

> The required arguments are an RFC 822 from-address string, a list of
>   RFC 822 to-address strings (a bare string will be treated as a list
>   with 1 address), and a message string.

You need to update your code where you call server.sendmail to include a from address and a to address and then your msg.

Comment: Thank you, finally I understood this. :)